# How To Use Styled component With Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form, styled-components

I have a react-typescript project I am working on currently. My engineering manager would insist that I use redux-form alongside styled-component.

my challenge is that I can't successfully find a way of getting this done. and I have browsed through a lot of online resources. I actually haven't found any possible help out there.

I would appreciate if anyone who probably have had to work with these two libraries (redux-form && styled-components) or just have an idea, can help out.

this is an instance of my code-base(what I've done so far)

`simple-field-input.styles.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { SimpleFieldProps } from './simple-field-input.type';

const ReduxFormField: React.FC<SimpleFieldProps> = ({ componentType }) => {
    return <Field component={componentType} name="email" id="email@us" className={'tes-hello'} />;
};
export const Container = styled(ReduxFormField)`
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: orangered;
    color: yellow;
`;
```

it displays the input element but doesn't reflect the style

thanks as you help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add some code of what you have tried to do?

Comment: @OrAssayag, I updated my question, kindly check again